# AS transaction_date created in SELECT but not found in WHERE statement, why?

Tags: date, datetime, google-bigquery, casting, where-clause

I'm looking to get order data from the past 30 rolling days. The goal, eventually, is to get this to pull some DISTINCTs so I can measure new orders/customers and order/customer churn along with one-time sales (there are some subscription and some onetime products in the database).

For starters, I'm just trying to pull all orders for the past 30 days.

Here's the query.

```
SELECT
  CAST(creation_date_transactions_orders AS DATE) as transaction_date,
  email_contact_transactions_orders,
  title_transactions_orders,
  total_paid_transactions_orders,
  status_transactions_orders
FROM
  `nla-analytics.NLA_Keap_Keap_Keap.transactions_orders` 
WHERE total_paid_transactions_orders IS NOT NULL 
AND status_transactions_orders LIKE "PAID"
AND transaction_date BETWEEN today() AND today() - 30
```

That's my query.

The problem is that BQ isn't recognizing "transaction_date" in the WHERE statement. "Unrecognized name: transaction_date

Why doesn't BQ recognize the field created a few lines previous, and how do I write this correctly?

Comment: It might be helpful for some if you posted the schema for this table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The alias created at the `SELECT` is not available in the `WHERE` in the same statement. From [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#where_clause):

> The WHERE clause only references columns available via the FROM clause; it cannot reference SELECT list aliases.

You can replicate the cast in WHERE or use a subquery:

```sql
WITH transactions AS (
    SELECT
        CAST(creation_date_transactions_orders AS DATE) as transaction_date,
        email_contact_transactions_orders,
        title_transactions_orders,
        total_paid_transactions_orders,
        status_transactions_orders
    FROM
        `nla-analytics.NLA_Keap_Keap_Keap.transactions_orders` 
    WHERE 
        total_paid_transactions_orders IS NOT NULL 
        AND status_transactions_orders LIKE "PAID"
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM transactions
WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN today() AND today() - 30
```